# How to keep illegal characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I'm using a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter` to read the content from a file, modify it and write it back to another file.

My original file comes from a machine and contains several ASCII control characters, notably char 0x01 "SOH" and char 0x02 "STX". When the `StreamReader` reads those characters into a string, the string no longer contains those.

Is there another way to force the StreamReader to keep those chars?

Comment: How do you read it? like `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mystring, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445907/force-c-sharp-to-use-ascii not sure if this will help but yeah, never had to do it myself so this is just a stab

Comment: @Alex yes this is how i do it

Comment: or use binary reader